# preventing page load re-insertion of data in db

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a  simple Registration Forrm with name and Address. When user fills and submits the form the data is inserted in DB.

And a Success alert message is shown.

If now user clicks refresh button the success alert box is shown and the same row is duplicated in DB.

How to avoid this.

i don't want to use if exist in db.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: http://aspalliance.com/687_Preventing_Duplicate_Record_Insertion_on_Page_Refresh.1

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you refreshing the page, the very previous click event will fire, this causes the re insertion in your DB. To avoid this check if page is refreshed/not on the button click event that.

```
public partial class Class1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   #region Code to Check Refresh postback
   #region Private Variable
   private int SessionValue
   {
    get
    {
        int value = default(int);
        if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(this.Session["__REFRESH"]), out value))
            return value;

        return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        this.Session["__REFRESH"] = value;
    }
   }

   private int ViewStateValue
   {
    get
    {
        int value = default(int);
        if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(this.ViewState["__REFRESH"]), out value))
            return value;

        return 0;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ViewState["__REFRESH"] = value;
    }
   }
   #endregion

   #region Public Property
   public bool IsPageRefreshed
   {
    get
    {
        return this.SessionValue != this.ViewStateValue;
    }
   }
   #endregion

   protected override object SaveViewState()
   {
    //Increment both the session and view state value at the same time.
    this.SessionValue = this.SessionValue == int.MaxValue ? 0 : this.SessionValue + 1;
    this.ViewStateValue = this.SessionValue == int.MaxValue ? 0 : this.SessionValue + 1;
    return base.SaveViewState();
   }
   #endregion


   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {       
   }

   protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (IsPageRefreshed)
       {
         // Here do your work. i.e save into DB.
       }
   }
}
```

Try this. Hope this what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

To really avoid duplicates you need to check if the data already exists in the database before inserting. If you just want to avoid this behaviour on page refresh you could redirect the user to another page after the insertion:

```
Response.Redirect("other_page.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in real word scenario you will have two options to handle the manual refresh scenario as you have explained.

1. While showing "And a Success alert message is shown." you could as for use "Your data saved successfully. Do you want to clear the form for next record? with Options of yes and no. When user clicks yes you should reset the form to original data entry state (to it's previous state where user started to fill the form). This will prevent the refresh scenario. You can also reset the form by default without showing the yes or no message.
2. Second is to redirect user to the same page of some other page where you list out the records of the entity for which you enter the record.  e.g From Add Employee page redirect to Employee listing page.

Hope you can implement any of these.